# UITextField Left View Mode .never Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I added a left view to my UITextField via:

```
customTextField.leftView = searchIconView
customTextField.leftViewMode = .always
```

However, I later need to remove that icon from my customTextField and make it look like the original. You would think that you could just do this and it would reset:

```
customTextField.leftView = nil
customTextField.leftViewMode = .never
```

This did not work. It got rid of my search icon, but the padding of the left view still acted like it was there. It just is this weird whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the answer to my own question:

I had to leave the customTextField.leftViewMode as .always once I had set it. Then, when I want to revert back to the original, I just set a new view for the Left View that is zero everything except has the original padding for the customTextField.

```
customTextField.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: customTextField.originalLeftPadding, height: 0)))
```

I get the original text field padding by subclassing UITextField for my customTextField, then I just hold onto the original left padding as a variable:

```
class CustomTextField : UITextField {
    var originalLeftPadding: CGFloat = 0

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        originalLeftPadding = leftPadding
    }
}
```